# Excel label creating

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet

I have the following problem! I am working in a restaurant, and I am in charge to prepare food labels for our buffet on a daily basis. I do know my way around excel. But still it gives me a headache to maintain hundreds of labels. The main problem is that they all have to contain a small picture, as a header, if I simply copy paste it through the cells, it starts to add up on each other and the sheet becomes slow and unresponsive. Is there a way or a macro to manage all these small pictures per cell?

Comment: First thing I would look at is the size of the image files. Assuming they get printed less than 1" in size, they should be about 250 kb if uncompressed and as low as 10-20 kb if compressed (as say JPEG files)

Comment: Have you looked into using label mail merge in Word? You could accomplish the exact same thing with fewer headaches by going that route. Excel is more for data processing while Word is better at word processing, which is what you're really looking for. I think the grid of Excel is what attracted you to the application, but Word has a wizard that will walk you through the entire process.